# Do I have to use google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){})?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm learning the Google Maps API and I was wondering whether I can use a jQuery click event in place of google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){}); to open an infoWindow or what are my options? Just finding out what's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use jQuery's `.bind()` method to get what you want.

You would have to make a jquery object out of `google.maps.Marker` and then call `.bind('click',function(){})` on it

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Hey, ive tried this but get an error: $(google.maps.Marker).bind('click', function(e){
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});  error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'setValues'

Comment: google.maps.Marker is an HTMLDocument, so I'm not sure if you can actually bind an action to it like that. Looking at google's documentation, I don't think there is a jQuery way to use it's addListener function... why do you need to use jQuery anyway? JavaScript is the same thing...

Comment: Hey Doug, no using Javascript is fine I just wanted to know if using vanilla js was the only real method to use or if I had other options as well just as part of learning this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy using the [jQuery ui map plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/). To address your question, [the basic example page](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-basic-example.html) lays out usage for creating an InfoWindow from a click:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function(ev, map) {
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {'position': '57.7973333,12.0502107',
                          'bounds': true}).click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {'content': 'Hello World!'}, 
                                   this);
    });
});
```

Personally I stick with plain JavaScript and follow the examples in the Google documentation. I vaguely remember a few other questions using this (or similar) plugin running into unwanted behavior that was unintuitively resolved by a "clearing" markers function, so beware if you use "convenience" tools that go between your ideas and the pure JavaScript for Google Maps. It may also be easier to get questions answered if the code is in plain JavaScript.